# Fetch info about a Facebook group's members

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My Facebook group has more than 2000 members, but using the following code I'm able only to get 25 members and not able fetch all data, only

- user_id
- first_name
- last name

And I am not able to fetch

- email
- phone
- gender
- birthday etc

  ```
  $request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/group_id/members',
    array(
      'fields' => 'id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,birthday'
    )
  );

  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
  ```

When I write limit parameter(2000) in the code I am getting the following error

> Please reduce the amount of data you're asking for, then retry your request.

Answer (score 0):

Do what the error message tells you and reduced the amount. Instead, use paging to get all members: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#paging

Btw, **you can only get the email and birthday of people who authorized your App with the correct permissions (email and user_birthday), and you can´t get the phone number at all**. You would not be allowed to store or use ANY data of the user anyway without his specific permission/authorization.

Also, you can´t get more than 5000 members, see this thread for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990562/how-do-i-bypass-the-facebook-graph-api-bug-and-get-more-than-5000-members-from-a

...but don´t do what the accepted answer suggests, because that would be scraping - which is not allowed on Facebook.

Here is the bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/267362886791339/

Comment: i tried with paging, i set `limit =4000&offset=0` and in response i got next -> `limit=4000&offset=4000`  with data response and in next loop i got `limit=4000&offset=8000` but didn't return data response. though there are more than 20000 members

Comment: afaik the limit parameter is very buggy, especially when it comes to very high limits. you should try a limit of 100 instead. i mean, you will not do those calls all the time, right? for page related object, there is even a specific maximum limit of 100. i assume that they will implement that maximum for other things sooner or later.

Comment: i need to export more than 20k data at a time

Comment: afaik you can´t get more than 5k, not sure if that is an intentional limitation or a bug, but it´s well known since a very long time so i assume it is intentional. either way, those high limits are very buggy in general. what do you need the members for anyway? you would not be allowed to use the data or store it anyway, without user authorization.

Comment: i´ve included the relevant bug report and some more information in my answer

Comment: thanks for reply. in above answer you mentioned 'you can only get the email and birthday of people who authorized your App' does it means people who are logged in using there account

Comment: of course. you can´t just grab the email or birthday of users just because they are member of a group, they have to authorize your app with the email and user_birthday permission. i have to ask again, what do you want to do with the email and birthday, especially with the email? do you want to store it? do you want to send members emails?

Comment: yes , i need to export this email id in .csv file. i can only fetch name and lastname and data less than 5000

Comment: you did not answer my question, WHAT FOR do you need the emails? "i want to export them into a CSV file" is not the answer to my question.

Comment: we need email id's so that we can contact them(client requirement)

Comment: read the bold part specifically, you are not supposed to get (or use) emails of users who did not authorize you specifically to do so. that would be a major privacy/data issue.

Comment: you can´t get the email of users without authorization for a good reason, you know. contacting them by email without their explicit permission would be spam. in other words: not possible and not allowed.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar and I'm confused why you can't get publicly available info.  There are users who are not friends of mine who show their hometown, birthday, etc publicly.  However when using the API, all of these fields don't come back.  Is this normal?

Comment: yes, this is normal. what would you do with the data anyway? just because it is public does not mean the user agreed that you can use his data in any way.